# DataStage API C++ Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Пытаюсь подключить API C++, но получаю ошибку.
Ссылка на API:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.3?topic=interfaces-infosphere-datastage-development-kit 
Ошибка: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135) 
Библиотеки добавлены в проекте, а так-же в System32. Что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dsapi.h"

int main() {
    DSSetServerParams("domain", "username", "password", "server");
    char* result = DSGetProjectList();
    if(result != NULL)
    {
        printf(result);
    }
    else
    {
        printf(DSGetLastError());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(datastage_api)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(vmdsapi SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        vmdsapi
        PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32"
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/vmdsapi.dll
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/vmdsapi.lib)

add_library(ACS_client_cpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        ACS_client_cpp
        PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32"
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/ACS_client_cpp.dll
)

add_library(ACS_common_cpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        ACS_common_cpp
        PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32"
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/ACS_common_cpp.dll)

add_library(DSCLNT32 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        DSCLNT32
        PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32"
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/DSCLNT32.dll)

add_library(dsrpc32 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        dsrpc32
        PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/dsrpc32.dll)

add_library(invocation_cpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        invocation_cpp
        PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/invocation_cpp.dll)

add_library(xmogrt STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
        xmogrt
        PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/xmogrt.dll)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_executable(datastage_api main.cpp )
set_target_properties(datastage_api PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")

target_link_libraries (datastage_api vmdsapi ACS_client_cpp ACS_common_cpp DSCLNT32 dsrpc32 invocation_cpp xmogrt)

add_custom_command(
        TARGET datastage_api POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/vmdsapi.dll"
        "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:datastage_api>")
```

Comment: cmake - интересная штука, он бинарник оставляет в подпапке, а программист (обычный) ожидает обычно, что бинарник будет в рабочем текущем каталоге. Самый простой способ - скопируйте dll  к exe и все будет ок.

Comment: @KoVadim Получилось подкинуть к релизному исполняемому файлу .exe, однако при запуске Cmake Dubug ошибка осталась. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за ответ. Ошибка сменилась на 0xc000007b, сможете так-же прокомментировать?

Comment: подождите, Вы подбросили длл к релизному, а запускаете дебаг? или это просто ошибка перевода?  ошибка 7b - это ошибка "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. " - похоже, это уже проблема самого апи, которое Вы используете.

Comment: @KoVadim При запуске Debug ошибка 0xC0000135. Понимаю что библиотек рядом нет, но где их тогда разместить?
При запуске скомпилированного exe (Release) подкинул длл, и тут ошибка изменилась на 0xc000007b. Это возможно из-за того, что dsapi.h реализован на C, а я добавляю его в проект C++?

Comment: с++ код почти всегда может использовать библиотеки, написанные на си. Си интерфейс практически стандарт де-факто для апи. Обратное не всегда верно. Библиотеки должны быть либо возле бинарника (exe) либо по доступным путям (некоторые копируют в каталог винды, но я строго не рекомендую это делать).

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)